# recommended typescript config for node 8

Tags: node.js, typescript

What is the recommended config for typescript if I want to ue the compiled sources with node 8?

most tutorials use the following *tsconig.json*:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs"
  }
}
```

But now I figured out, that not all available features are supported. For example `['foo'].includes('bar')` throws the error: *Property 'includes' does not exist on type 'string[]'.*

I found an [issue](https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter/issues/931) that addresses this problem. The solution is to use the lib `es7`.
I could overwrite the default libs: `"lib": ["es7"]`

But I'm not sure if this is the best config for node 8 - are there more features which are not supported by that lib? are there to much features defined?

So my question is: What are the best configurations for `target`, `lib` and `module` if I want to use node 8?

Answer (score 116, accepted):

As of Node.js `8.10.0`, 100% of ES2017 is supported. If you know that you are targeting that version or newer, the optimal config would look like this:

- `"module": "commonjs"`

  Node.js is on it's way to add ES-Modules, but for now we'll have to stick with CommonJS.
- `"target": "es2017"`

  This tells TypeScript that it's okay to output JavaScript *syntax* with features from ES2017. In practice, this means that it will e.g. output `async`/`await` instead of embedding a polyfill (`__awaiter`).
- `"lib": ["es2017"]`

  This tells TypeScript that it's okay to use *functions and properties* introduced in ES2017 or earlier. In practice, this means that you can use e.g. `Array.prototype.includes` and `String.prototype.padStart`.

The full config would thus be:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2017"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2017"
  }
}
```

---

If you are running Node.js 18 you can see my [similar answer for Node.js 18 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72380008/148072)

If you are running Node.js 16 you can see my [similar answer for Node.js 16 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67371788/148072)

If you are running Node.js 14 you can see my [similar answer for Node.js 14 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61305579/148072)

If you are running Node.js 12 you can see my [similar answer for Node.js 12 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59787575/148072)

If you are running Node.js 10 you can see my [similar answer for Node.js 10 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57607634/148072)

Comment: I'm trying to find something confirming that 8.10.0+ supports 100% of ES2017. Kangax's compatibility table only shows 8.9.x so it's outdated. The node changelog doesn't make any claim about ES2017 compatibility. Do you have a source for this?

Comment: https://node.green/ is an updated version of the Kangax table, specifically tailored for Node.js versions, that's what I was looking at 

Comment: Wow, I looked at node.green and would never have discovered that, because it's buried under the 9.11.1 header. I wish there was a way to specify the versions shown in the table. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I'm not sure but shouldn't the noLib option be specified for node?

Comment: is Promise.finally supported in ES2017? Because it isn't by Node 8

Comment: @velop `Promise.finally` is a part of ES2018, not ES2017. It's supported by Node.js 10.0.0 and newer. If you are running Node.js 10, see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57607634/148072

Answer (score 5):

I'm sure you've already found this but there is Microsoft's starter template here: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Node-Starter

Whilst you are still on Node 8.x, keep your `module` set to `commonjs`, `target` can be `es6`.

`compilerOptions.lib` only defines what declarations the compiler uses for compile time checks, it does not affect the output of `tsc`. In other words, you can use whatever `lib` you want and not worry that your transpiled code will be any different (this is controlled entirely by `compilerOptions.target`).

Using `es7` as a `lib` in your case will be fine and will give you type declarations for ES7 and under.

`Array.includes` is ES7 (ES2016) and therefore as you've discovered is not part of `ES6`. You could define your `lib` as; `lib: ["es6", "ES2016.Array.Include"]` to get around your issue.

Comment: According to http://node.green/ you could target `es2016` safely in Node 8.9.4, you could probably get away with targeting `es2017` if you want to use native async/await.

Answer (score 4):

There's a page in the [TypeScript wiki](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Node-Target-Mapping) which lists recommended TSConfig settings for various node versions.