# TypeScript tsconfig settings for Node.js 10?

Tags: node.js, typescript, compilation

Does anyone know which target/libs are required for Node.js v10.x to use the built in async/await without the generators? I see a lot for node 8 but not with node 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find the latest Typescript target support for any version of node?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54012303/how-do-i-find-the-latest-typescript-target-support-for-any-version-of-node)

Answer (score 92, accepted):

As of Node.js `10.0.0`, 100% of ES2018 is supported. If you know that you are targeting that version or newer, the optimal config would look like this:

- `"module": "commonjs"`

  Node.js is on its way to add ES-Modules, but for now we'll have to stick with CommonJS.
- `"target": "es2018"`

  This tells TypeScript that it's okay to output JavaScript *syntax* with features from ES2018. In practice, this means that it will e.g. output object rest/spread properties & async/await syntax instead of embedding a polyfill.
- `"lib": ["es2018"]`

  This tells TypeScript that it's okay to use *functions and properties* introduced in ES2018 or earlier. In practice, this means that you can use e.g. `Promise.prototype.finally`, `Array.prototype.includes` and `String.prototype.padStart`.

The full config would thus be:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2018"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2018"
  }
}
```

---

If you are running Node.js 18 you can see my [similar answer for Node.js 18 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72380008/148072)

If you are running Node.js 16 you can see my [similar answer for Node.js 16 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67371788/148072)

If you are running Node.js 14 you can see my [similar answer for Node.js 14 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61305579/148072)

If you are running Node.js 12 you can see my [similar answer for Node.js 12 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59787575/148072)

If you are running Node.js 8 you can see my [similar answer for Node.js 8 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50466512/148072)

Comment: Why not `"lib": ["esnext"]`? You want to be able to use the latest features when writing code. Any features that don't exist in the `target` will be transformed by the typescript compiler to work on that target.

Comment: @VivekMaharajh TypeScript doesn't add polyfills for e.g. `Promise.prototype.finally`, so if you use `"lib": ["esnext"]` you might accidentally use functions that aren't available in Node.js 10. With the posted answer, you will still be able to take advantage of all new _language features_, just not new _library functions_, since they won't be available on your target.

Comment: Oh, good to know. I always assumed that the typescript compiler would fail if it couldn't transpile the source code into the target.

Comment: Did anything change for node 12?

Comment: @Tom Yes it did, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59787575/148072

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @LinusUnnebäck ! Just to be clear: A language feature would be something like arrow syntax vs. a library function is anything related to the standard lib such as Promise.allSettled()?

Comment: I wouldn't use the phrase "language feature" to make that distinction, as it is ambiguous to me in this context. I think @LinusUnnebäck is spot on in his answer, writing about  _syntax_ vs _standard library_ ("functions and properties").

Answer (score 7):

According to [recommended typescript config for node 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48378495/recommended-typescript-config-for-node-8) , `--target ES2017` is supported on Node 8.10.0 and newer (which would include Node 10), and it is sufficient to pass through async functions to the output without translating them to generators.

Comment: Node 10 supports 100% of ES2018 features so you can target that https://node.green/#ES2018