# Which TypeScript target and libs should I use in a Node.js project without transpilers?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

Let's say I'm running TypeScript Node.js project like this: `tsc && node build/index.js` (and tsc builds into `build/` and I have `index.ts` in the project).

What values should I use in `lib` and `target` (`tsconfig.json`) to get the best possible experience, ie. access to newest features in my TypeScript code and output newest possible JavaScript code that still runs well on vanilla `node` without Babel or other transpilers.

I'm using a new version of Node (`10.11.0` is the official current version now) but I'd appreciate a more general answer that is not specific to this version.

Comment: You might want to check out [`ts-node`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node) as well!

Comment: `ts-node` is really nice, however, this question is not about how to run my code but about optimal compiler settings :)

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716406/typescript-tsconfig-settings-for-node-js-10

Answer (score 0):

Looking at https://node.green it seems that Node `10.11.0` supports 99% of ES2015 and 100% of ES2016 and ES2017 so

```
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": ["es2017"],
    "module": "commonjs",
```

would be a good starting point.