# How do I find the latest Typescript target support for any version of node?

Tags: node.js, typescript, compiler-options, ecma

Assuming any version of Node, how do I find the corresponding Typescript [Compiler Option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html) for `target` that gives most the functionality? I want to remove the guest work.

> Specify ECMAScript target version: "ES3" (default), "ES5", "ES6"/"ES2015", "ES2016", "ES2017" or "ESNext".

I run different versions of node, and I want to know when is the minimum node version to enable the different TSC targets.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One method to accomplish this is to check out the site http://node.green. Find your version of node, and scroll down until the support for node features stops. So, for example, if you're using 10.3

[image: ES2018 support]

Then you can see that

- 10.3.0 and later supports all of ES2018.
- 9.11.2 and latter supports all of ES2017.
- 7.5.0 and later supports all of ES2016.

ES2016 support is a bit more complex thanks to `Array.Prototype.values` which [node.green doesn't register as being supported until 10.15.0](https://node.green/#ES2015-built-in-extensions-Array-prototype-methods-Array-prototype-values).