# Wildcard imports not working in node14 with es2020

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm working on an express application and I'm having trouble with wildcard imports, such as `import * as E from 'fp-ts/Either';`

Error message:

```
Error \[ERR\_MODULE\_NOT\_FOUND\]: Cannot find module '/home/adam/code/rbsports/server/node\_modules/fp-ts/Either' imported from /home/adam/code/rbsports/server/dist/controllers/bracket.js

Did you mean to import fp-ts/lib/Either.js?
```

Are wildcard imports not supported for a node 14 app targeting es2020?

my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "es2020",
    "target": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  }
}
```

and im running the app with `node  --experimental-specifier-resolution=node .` in the folder with package.json

relevant parts of package.json

```
{
  ...
  "type": "module",
  "main": "dist/app.js"
  ...
}
```

followed [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61305578/what-typescript-configuration-produces-output-closest-to-node-js-14-capabilities/61305579#61305579) and [this github repo](https://github.com/dandv/typescript-modern-project#import-your-own-modules-without-specifying-an-extension)

Answer (score 0):

This may be an issue with how you are importing. I think `Either` lives in `fp-ts/lib/Either` and you’re importing from `fp-ts/Either`

**Edit:** the error message you posted says this as well I’ve just noticed