# Importing a CommonJS module in a Typescript project exporting ESModules

Tags: node.js, typescript, ecmascript-2020

I am making a NodeJs library in Typescript and I plan to make it support Node@14+. So, I decided to base this project as a ESModule instead of CommonJs. Now there are some libraries required that are CommonJs and I am installing their `@types`. The imports of my typescript file looks like this:

```js
import { Command } from 'commander';
import inquirer from 'inquirer';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import { render } from 'mustache';

import { copySync, readdirSync, readFile, readFileSync, writeFile } from 'fs-extra';
```

and the `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```json
{
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    // type checking
    "exactOptionalPropertyTypes": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitOverride": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noPropertyAccessFromIndexSignature": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "strict": true,
    // module
    "module": "ES2020",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    // emit
    "outDir": "dist",
    //    "importHelpers": true,
    // imterop constraints
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    // language and environment
    "lib": ["ES2020"],
    "target": "ES2020",
    // completeness
    "skipLibCheck": true
  }
}
```

As you can see, I am targeting ES2020 as that is fully supported by Node@14+ and I based my config on the incredible answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/61305579/5863472. Also, I am setting `"type": "module"` in my `package.json`.

This builds with no problem but doesn't run. The error thrown by Node is

> import { copySync, readdirSync, readFile, readFileSync, writeFile } from 'fs-extra';
>
> ^^^^^^^^
>
> SyntaxError: Named export 'readFile' not
> found. The requested module 'fs-extra' is a CommonJS module, which may
> not support all module.exports as named exports.
>
> CommonJS modules can always be imported via the default export, for example using:
>
> import pkg from 'fs-extra';
>
> const { copySync, readdirSync, readFile, readFileSync, writeFile } = pkg;

The same codebase compiles well using `"module": "ES2020"` in my `tsconfig.json` and removing the `type` key in my `package.json`.

The way I have found to work around this is by following the error message. This works fine:

```js
import { Command } from 'commander';
import inquirer from 'inquirer';
import { resolve } from 'path';
import mustache from 'mustache';
import fs from 'fs-extra';

const { copySync, readdirSync, readFile, readFileSync, writeFile } = fs;
const { render } = mustache;
```

But this feels like such a pain and seems like something that could be tooled. Am I missing and compilation option or something that can automatically convert `import { foo } from 'bar'` to `import bar from 'bar'; const { foo } = bar`.

P.S. I really don't want to use Babel...