# Typescript compilerOptions module & moduleResolution

Tags: node.js, typescript

I find many tsconfig.json samples always have `compilerOptions` like this

```
"module": "commonjs",
"moduleResolution": "node"
```

I feel setting them both as such seems unnecessary because if `moduleResolution` is `node` the `module` is definitely `commonjs`. The `module` is `commonjs`, `moduleResolution` is definitely `node` too (I can't think of any other case)

Isn't that is the case?

--- update ---

Now I realize it is not always the case because nodejs has fully support ES Modules, so I can use `"module": "ES2020" & "moduleResolution": "node"` (for nodejs 14+) but of course if I set `"module":"commonjs"` I don't need to set `"moduleResolution": "node"`

Further refer to [What TypeScript configuration produces output closest to Node.js 14 capabilities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61305578/what-typescript-configuration-produces-output-closest-to-node-js-14-capabilities)

Answer (score 3):

Being explicit about configuration can prevent undesired behavior if a default value changes in the future in a breaking way.

The [documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig) explains the relationships between these configuration properties. I'll inline the default behaviors below:

[`moduleResolution`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#moduleResolution):

> Default:
>
> `Classic` if [module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module) is `AMD`, `UMD`, `System` or `ES6`/`ES2015`,
>
> Matches if [module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module) is `node12` or `nodenext`,
>
> `Node` otherwise.
>
> Allowed:
>
> - `classic`
> - `node`

[`module`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#module):

> Default:
>
> `CommonJS` if [target](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target) is `ES3` or `ES5`,
>
> `ES6`/`ES2015` otherwise.
>
> Allowed:
>
> - `none`
> - `commonjs`
> - `amd`
> - `umd`
> - `system`
> - `es6`/`es2015`
> - `es2020`
> - `es2022`
> - `esnext`
> - `node12`
> - `nodenext`

[`target`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target):

> Default:
>
> `ES3`
>
> Allowed:
>
> - `es3`
> - `es5`
> - `es6`/`es2015`
> - `es2016`
> - `es2017`
> - `es2018`
> - `es2019`
> - `es2020`
> - `es2021`
> - `esnext`

Comment: My question is set them both as such, "module": "commonjs" & "moduleResolution": "node" seems no need.

Comment: Both are the defaults, so neither one is necessary. If you want to output a CJS module, set `module` to `commonjs`, and then you don't need to explicitly set the value of `moduleResolution`.

Comment: Hi check my update

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: I have to say the question I quoted answered my question but your answer didn't (at least not from my point of view). So I just upvoted your answer instead of accepting it.

Comment: So I updated my question to answer it myself.