# 'Invalid lambda response received' when specifying headers through an imported const

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I'm using CDK typescript lambda stack, connected to an API Gateway.
Everything works just fine when I'm sending the following response:

```
const res = await request<ResponseModel>(req);
return {
    statusCode: res.status,
    headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(res.data)
};
```

However, I've tried to set the headers with a common const, and the result is a failure:

```
// common-headers.ts
export const CommonResponseHeaders = {
  'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
  'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': true
};

//function.ts
import { CommonResponseHeaders } from '../../common/common-headers';

const res = await request<ResponseModel>(req);
return {
    statusCode: res.status,
    headers: CommonResponseHeaders,
    body: JSON.stringify(res.data)
};

//stack.ts
const function = {
    name: 'myFunction',
    runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
    entry: path.join(__dirname, './function.ts'),
    vpcSubnets: {
      subnetType: SubnetType.PRIVATE_WITH_EGRESS
    },
    handler: 'handler',
    environment: {
      ...SomeDefaultVariables
    }
  }
const lambda = new NodejsFunction(this, function.name, function);
const functionUrl = lambda.addFunctionUrl({
authType: FunctionUrlAuthType.NONE,
cors: {
  allowedOrigins: ['*'],
}
});
new CfnOutput(this, `${function.name}-FunctionUrl`, {
value: functionUrl.url,
});
```

> Invalid lambda response received: Invalid API Gateway Response Keys:
> {'trace', 'errorType', 'errorMessage'} in {'errorType': 'TypeError',
> 'errorMessage': "Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined", 'trace':
> ["TypeError: Cannot read property 'trim' of undefined", '    at
> Object. (/var/task/index.js:10924:40)', '    at
> Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)', '    at
> Object.Module._extensions..js
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)', '    at Module.load
> (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)', '    at
> Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)', '
> at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)', '    at
> require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)', '    at
> _tryRequireFile (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:72:32)', '    at _tryRequire (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:160:20)', '    at _loadUserApp (/var/runtime/UserFunction.js:219:12)']}

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is `common-headers` bundled properly in the Lambda code artefact?  What construct are you using for the Lambda function resource?

Comment: @fedonev I'm having trouble answering your questions so I guess that I miss some basic understandings of how the CDK really works. I'm using `CfnOutput` construct. How would I bundle my file into the lambda? I thought that importing it would be enough (just as I'm importing modules such as axios)

Comment: No worries, let me rephrase:  Q1:  Do you see `common-headers.js` bundled in the Lambda function code? (hypothesis: no)  Q2:  How are you defining your Lambda Function? (please add some minimal CDK code to the question)

Comment: @fedonev I don't see the `common-headers.js` file but the code itself gets bundeled into `index.js`. I'll update my question

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in your setup.  I am all out of ideas, sorry.

Comment: What happens if you removed the dot '.' in this line entry: path.join(__dirname, './function.ts'),        
==>'/function.ts'

Comment: @MahmoudNasr nothing changed, same error

Comment: make sure the file path is right such as ../function.ts check the file level, these combinations

Comment: Wouldn't the deployment fail as the file path is incorrect...?

Comment: Did you follow the trace? What code do you see at `/var/task/index.js:10924:40`?

Comment: Try this: import { CommonResponseHeaders } from '../../common/common-headers.js';

Answer (score 0):

There is a mismatch between the headers your code returns and what API Gateway expects. Looking at your code example, if your response succeeds, it returns the correct headers. According to the AWS [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-integration-settings-integration-response.html), the Lambda function must return output of the following format:

```
{
    statusCode: "...",            // a valid HTTP status code
    headers: { 
        custom-header: "..."      // any API-specific custom header
    },
    body: "...",                  // a JSON string.
    isBase64Encoded:  true|false  // for binary support
}
```

So something else in your project is causing this error, and this error is not handled properly. If you encounter an error, you should return a 4xx or 5xx status code in the format described above. However, since your example is pretty small, I suppose this will not throw any errors. It is probably caused by the CDK framework in which your code is loaded. Specifically, I would look at the following things:

1. There is a related [issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-hosting/issues/2148) about AWS amplify, where someone misspelled `approot`, where it should have been `appRoot`. He got exactly the same error complaining about the trim function.
2. You must configure your TypeScript transpilation settings to match the Node.js runtime that you plan to use. Check out [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-typescript.html) documentation from AWS for more information on runtimes.
3. When using NodeJS 14.x, you should double-check if your imports match the requirements for that specific version. A mistake is easily made when copying code from somewhere else. I suggest you carefully read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61305579/7950592), it describes that in your case local files should be imported as follows (although that might seem weird):

   ```
    // Actual file is ../../common/common-headers.ts
    import { CommonResponseHeaders } from '../../common/common-headers.js';
   ```

Comment: Thanks, but none of those three suggestions were relevant to my code unfortunately.

Comment: Please post your tsconfig.json with your answer to have a little more information on your environment

Answer (score 0):

> It's causing issue because it couldn't able to detect your imports properly.

**Did you correctly imported common-headers.ts file so your CommonResponseHeaders?**

You should try to specify paths in another file named `config.json` where you could do something like this:

Just make sure you add the common-headers.ts file path in **include**.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
    },
    "include": [
        "./src/**/*",
        "./common/**/*"
    ]
}
```

Now try to deploy using CDK, this should include your common-headers.ts properly and will fix your issue.

**Note:** Still not working? Maybe check your import statement and see if you correctly importing CommonResponseHeaders from common-headers.ts file or not

Comment: Thanks @Myth, that change didn't work. Regarding the `import` note, I'm also importing other stuff that work as expected so I don't think this is an import statement issue.

Comment: Yes it is probably the node.js runtime version of the lambda, which doesn’t support the import, that is why I proposed to check all this. But it is difficult to figure this out without having all those details. Later versions of node.js and transpiler support more/different import options. The lambda only runs under version node.js 14.

Comment: So again, it might seem to work locally. It breaks when running in a lambda.

Comment: Hmm I think then your CommonResponseHeaders is not able to bundle properly with lambda but I'm not sure, maybe try to see logs of lambda func or print the variable CommonResponseHeaders before returning so can you can make sure it's an object and have expected values once. Other then this Idk bro, Sorry