# What TypeScript configuration produces output closest to Node.js 18 capabilities?

Tags: node.js, typescript

How would I configure TypeScript in order to take advantage of all the latest features in Node.js 18? Specifically I would like to know how to get full support for ESM, and how to use all the latest syntax and functions introduced in ES2021/ES2022.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

As of Node.js `18.0.0`, 100% of ES2022 is supported (apart from a bug in RegEx.flags), and support for ES Modules is stable! If you know that you are targeting that version or newer, the optimal config would look like this:

- `"module": "ES2022"` & `"moduleResolution": "node"`

  Node.js 18 support loading modules instead of the old CommonJS format, we do have to tell TypeScript that we are using Node.js's rules for resolving modules.
- `"allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true`

  To provide backwards compatibility, Node.js allows you to import CommonJS packages with a default import. This flag tells TypeScript that it's okay to use `import` on CommonJS modules.
- `"target": "ES2022"`

  This tells TypeScript that it's okay to output JavaScript *syntax* with features from ES2022. In practice, this means that it will e.g. output logical assignment operators & async/await syntax instead of embedding a polyfill.
- `"lib": ["ES2022"]`

  This tells TypeScript that it's okay to use *functions and properties* introduced in ES2022 or earlier. In practice, this means that you can use e.g. `Promise.any` and `String.prototype.replaceAll`.

The full config would thus be:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "lib": ["ES2022"],
    "module": "ES2022",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "ES2022"
  }
}
```

In addition to this, we also need to tell Node.js to treat `.js` files in this project as ES Modules. The reason for this is that Node.js had to maintain backwards compatibility with code written for older Node.js versions. This can be done by adding `"type": "module"` to your `package.json`:

```
{
  "type": "module"
}
```

Another change if you are coming from an earlier version of Node.js is that [the file extensions when importing files are now mandatory](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/esm.html#esm_mandatory_file_extensions). This means that you must write out `.js` at the end of your local imports. Note that this is `.js` even though you are importing a TypeScript file that actually has the file extension `.ts`. This might seem a bit confusing but [this comment from one of the TS contributors explains why that is](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35589#issuecomment-564644320).

Here are some examples of how to write your `import` statements:

```
// Built-in Node.js modules
import { readFileSync } from 'fs'

// CommonJS packages from Npm
import md5File from 'md5-file'

// The local file "a.ts"
import { a } from './a.js'
```

---

If you want to stick with CommonJS for now, to avoid the caveats explained above, you can use the following config:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["ES2022"],
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "ES2022"
  }
}
```

---

If you are running Node.js 16 you can see my [similar answer for Node.js 16 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67371788/148072)

If you are running Node.js 14 you can see my [similar answer for Node.js 14 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61305579/148072)

If you are running Node.js 12 you can see my [similar answer for Node.js 12 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59787575/148072)

If you are running Node.js 10 you can see my [similar answer for Node.js 10 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57607634/148072)

If you are running Node.js 8 you can see my [similar answer for Node.js 8 here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50466512/148072)

Comment: I wanted to point out that namespace imports no longer work either. If you have an `index.ts` in a directory, you'll have to access it directly, e.g.: `import { myUtilFunc } from './utils/index.js`.

Comment: Hello, I have the above configuration but TypeScript is still complaining about using globals like `fetch` and `Request`,  `Cannot find name 'fetch'.ts(2304)`

Comment: @expandstudios have you installed the `@types/node` package at version 18.x?

Comment: Why not `"moduleResolution": "node16"`? Can you clarify that?

Comment: Agree with @pkerschbaum Should use "module" and "moduleResolution" of "Node16" and you won't have to worry about rewriting you imports.

Comment: @expandstudios You need to add "dom" into the "lib" if you want to use the Fetch APIs of Node 18.  Right now TypeScript doesn't have a lib that supports Node16 or Node18

Comment: If I set `"type": "module"` then I can't use `require` but there are some packages, e.g. [debugjs](https://github.com/debug-js/debug) is still cmj only.

Comment: how to import .json files with these settings?