# Typescript compilation extremely slow

Tags: typescript

There are a few questions on this already but I have not seen anyone with compilation as slow as mine.

I have a node/express project:

```
ls src/**/*.ts | wc -l
25

cat src/**/*.ts | wc -l
2618
```

It's very small. 25 files comprising about 2600 lines of code.

When I run:

```
tsc --diagnostics
```

from the **root** of the project folder (which contains `tsconfig.json` and `src/`)

I get:

```
Files:              1629 <---- what??
Lines:           2347286
Identifiers:     1749641
Symbols:          997960
Types:            245321
Instantiations:    70082
Memory used:    1820643K <---- what??
I/O read:          1.08s
I/O write:         0.02s
Parse time:       11.13s
Bind time:         4.24s
Check time:        9.11s
Emit time:         0.14s
Total time:       24.62s
```

Why are so many files used? It takes up so much memory and time which just doesn't seem right for such a small project. It takes about 6 minutes to run on a less powerful machine and I need to set the memory limit to be higher. `exclude` doesn't seem to be working and my suspicion is that typescript is compiling my whole `node_modules` folder. I have tried as many glob patterns as I could think of to exclude, and I updated my config to `es2022` as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72380008/589921) answer.

edit: I have tried adding:

```
"types": [],
"skipLibCheck": true
```

and it makes no difference on time, memory, or files used.

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "audio diary server",
  "main": "./build/src/index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/cron": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.9",
    "@types/jwk-to-pem": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/node": "^18.7.18",
    "@types/node-fetch": "^2.6.3",
    "@types/passport": "^1.0.7",
    "@types/passport-google-oauth2": "^0.1.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.37.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.37.0",
    "eslint": "^8.23.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.31.8",
    "sucrase": "^3.29.0",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.32.0",
    "@mailchimp/mailchimp_marketing": "^3.0.80",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.7.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1183.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cron": "^2.1.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "filereader": "^0.10.3",
    "fs": "^0.0.1-security",
    "get-audio-duration": "^3.1.1",
    "googleapis": "^92.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "jwk-to-pem": "^2.0.5",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "mysql": "^2.14.1",
    "openai": "^3.2.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "typeorm": "0.2.41"
  },
  
}
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2022", "dom"],
    "module": "es2022",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es2022",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

Comment: Have you tried turning it (your computer) off and on again? Try a restart.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that. As I said in my question, it runs slow on multiple machines